# Rename File in aws glue scala

Tags: aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

I am writing files to S3 using glue scala code. But it saves csv file as run-part-000.. I want it to save or rename as something.csv. How can it be done? Code snippet below-

```
gluecontext.getSinkWithFormat(
connectionType = "S3",
options = JsonOptions(Map("path" -> "s3://somepath/somefolder"))
format = 'csv',
formatOptions = JsonOptions(Map("withHeader" -> true, "quoteChar" = -1))
transformationContext = " " )
.writeDynamicFrame(df)
)
```

Comment: Any luck on this Abhishek?

Comment: No, seems part files are created by mappers so the naming convention can't be changed